# Tracker autorun using findone

Tags: meteor

I have this piece of code in client side:

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
    if (params && params._id) {
        const dept = Department.findOne({ _id: params._id }) || Department.findOne({ name: params._id });
        if (dept) {
        }
    }
});
```

params will be passed into the url. So, initially we won't have the department data and the findOne method will return null, and then later on, when data arrives, we can find the department object.

But if user enters an invalid id, we need to return them 404. Using tracker autorun, how can I distinguish between 2 cases:

a. Data is not there yet, so findOne returns null

b. There is no such data, even in server's mongodb, so findOne will also returns null.

For case a, tracker autorun will work fine, but for case b, I need to know to return 404

Comment: What means data is not there yet? `findOne` should never return null but a cursor, which may contain no data to be fetched (checkable via `count()` size equal or greater zero)

Comment: because I need to wait for data from the server

Comment: @Jankapunkt, `findOne` does not return a cursor, it returns the document or null

Comment: Facepalm, true. Confused it with find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to subscribe to data inside template, like below so you know when subscriptions are ready, then you can check data exists or not

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function onCreated() {
  const self = this;
  const id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
  self.subscribe('department', id);
});


Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function onRendered() {
  const self = this;
  // this will run after subscribe completes sending records to client
  if (self.subscriptionsReady()) {
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
    const dept = Department.findOne({ _id: params._id }) || Department.findOne({ name: params._id });
    if (dept) {
      // found data in db
    } else {
      // 404 - no department found in db

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Iron-Router, you may try this hack.

```
Router.route('/stores', function() {
    this.render('stores', {});
}, {
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('stores_db')
        ];
    }
});
```

The sample code above will wait for the subscription "stores_db" to complete, before rendering anyhing. Then you can use your `findOne` logic no problems, ensuring that all documents are availble. This suits your situation.

This is what I used to do before I completely understand MeteorJS publications and subscriptions. I do not recommend my solution, it is very bad to user experience. Users will see the page loading forever while the documents are being download. @Sasikanth gave the correct implementation.